# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc is returning the wrong value

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, datetime-conversion

I'm taking a set date/time value and converting from UTC, but timezone. I'm expecting to get the original time - 5 to be the correct time in the EST time zone, but it is off by 1 hour and only offset it by 4 hours.

```
string dateString = "3/15/2021 6:59 AM";
DateTime TimeDataDue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var TimeDataDueEastern = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(TimeDataDue, easternZone).Dump();
```

The output I get is "3/15/2021 2:59:00 AM", but I expect to get "3/15/2021 1:59:00 AM"

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: The date/time you got is correct, because it falls into DST transition (for EST that's +1 hour from March till November). Remember that a time zone = UTC offset + DST rules.

Comment: Thank You, this makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

As Yarik said in the question comments, the result you obtained is correct.

You can review the 2021 DST schedule for the US Eastern Time zone here:
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york?year=2021

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screnshot 2]

Additionally, you'll note that `easternZone.DisplayName` in your code will be `"(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`  (assuming English).  In other words, despite the time zone having the word "Standard" in its `Id`, it applies for the entire year including both EST and EDT periods.

Since EDT is in effect on March 15th 2021, you get a result that is four hours behind UTC.